# How to automatically generate stub for method generated by meta programming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, rubymine

One of utility class in my codebase generates class methods dynamically using meta programming.

My problem:

1. Currently, Rubymine is not able to suggest such methods and
   complains that it cannot find `FeatureFlagHandler.foo_enabled?`
   method.
2. How can I let Rubymine learn about these dynamic methods? I
   want Rubymine to suggest such methods for code completion so that
   when I type `FeatureFlagHandler.fo` it should be able to suggest
   `FeatureFlagHandler.foo_enabled?` method.

Source Code of class:

```rb
class FeatureFlagHandler
  class << self
    # Generates `_enabled?` and `_disabled?` helper methods for feature flags
    # for all Constants defined in AppUtils::FeatureFlags
    # 
    #      module AppUtils
    #        module FeatureFlags
    #          FOO = "FOO"
    #          BAR = "BAR"
    #        end
    #      end
    #
    # e.g. If AppUtils::FeatureFlags contains FOO and BAR constant, then
    #      below code will generate following method definitions:
    #
    #      def self.foo_enabled?
    #        enabled?("FOO")
    #      end
    #      def self.bar_enabled?
    #        enabled?("BAR")
    #      end
    #
    # Then above methods can be used as:
    #
    # do_something if FeatureFlagHandler.foo_enabled?
    #
    AppUtils::FeatureFlags.constants.each do |flag|
      define_method("#{flag.to_s.downcase}_enabled?") do
        # Logic to check if `feature_flag` is ON or OFF
        # For eg:
        ENV[feature_flag] == "ENABLE"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note: Feature-flags are regularly added/removed from above `AppUtils::FeatureFlags` module

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using YARD `@!macro` but unfortunately that one isn't supported yet in RubyMine, there's a corresponding request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20130